# Run Teamviewer on debian jessie

Tags: debian, software-installation, teamviewer

I have installed `teamviewer_11.0.53191_i386.deb` on my debian jessie system:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)
Release:        8.7
Codename:       jessie
```

However, I get:

[image]

On my machine all outgoing ports are open, but I also enabled the teamviewer ports:

```
root@www:/home/root# netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      445/xrdp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      838/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2751/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5902            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2955/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5903            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11585/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58799           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      364/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5904            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11617/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5905            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11656/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2751/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5906            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11685/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2955/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10594/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8787            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16440/rserver
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5907            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11734/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11585/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5908            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11993/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6004            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11617/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11656/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6006            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11685/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5910          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3082/Xvnc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      447/xrdp-sesman
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6007            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11734/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6008            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11993/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      468/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      840/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::58799                :::*                    LISTEN      364/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      840/apache2
```

I further tried to `teamviewer --daemon restart` but I still get no connection.

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

**UPDATE**

I installed the latest version of teamviewer but still get `Not  ready. Please check your connection.`

```
root@www:/home/marcus/Downloads# gdebi teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
Building data structures... Done

Remote control and meeting solution.
 TeamViewer provides easy, fast and secure remote access and meeting solutions
 to Linux, Windows PCs, Apple PCs and various other platforms,
 including Android and iPhone.
 .
 TeamViewer is free for personal use.
 You can use TeamViewer completely free of charge to access your private
 computers or to help your friends with their computer problems.
 .
 To buy a license for commercial use, please visit http://www.teamviewer.com
 .
 This package contains Free Software components.
 For details, see /opt/teamviewer/doc/license_foss.txt
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer.
(Reading database ... 75352 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer (12.0.71510) ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/var/log/teamviewer11': Directory not empty
Setting up teamviewer (12.0.71510) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
root@www:/home/marcus/Downloads# teamviewer --daemon start

systemctl start teamviewerd.service
```

Below you can find the output of `sudo systemctl status teamviewerd.service`

```
root@www:/home/root/Downloads# sudo systemctl status teamviewerd.service -l
* teamviewerd.service - TeamViewer remote control daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-02-19 09:13:13 CET; 3min 55s ago
  Process: 3612 ExecStart=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d (code=exited, st                                               atus=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3614 (teamviewerd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/teamviewerd.service
           `-3614 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d

Feb 19 09:13:13 www systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/teamviewerd.pid not readable (                                               yet?) after start.
Feb 19 09:13:13 www systemd[1]: Started TeamViewer remote control daemon.
Feb 19 09:13:58 www systemd[1]: Started TeamViewer remote control daemon.
```

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status teamviewerd.service` ?

Comment: Try a tcpdump, where it tries to communicate.

Comment: @GAD3R How can I get this output?

Comment: Just open the terminal and run `sudo systemctl status teamviewerd.service`

Comment: @Kare , there are a new version here :https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/ , remove the old one then install it with `gdebi`

Comment: @GAD3R Please see my update.

Comment: @peterh All outbound connections are working on my server. There is no problem with port 80 HTTP, 443 HTTPs or 5938 TCP. Any other suggestions?

Comment: seems a common issue, for some reason: https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-12/Not-ready-Please-check-your-connection-after-upgrade-to-v12/td-p/2177

Comment: This issues appeared after release of version 12, and when i upgraded  to version 12 everything worked fine.